# sed with variables fails to replace value

Tags: bash, sed

I wrote the following command:

```
var=$(printf "$line" | awk -F':' {'print $2'} | sed 's/,//g')
sed -i "s/$var/exampletext/g" "file.txt"
```

The text is part of a larger script that finds a specific value, and then replaces it with another value.

The basic end result I want is something like this:

```
sed -i "s/123/exampletext/g" "file.txt"
```

That should replace all of the `123`'s in file.txt with `exampletext`. When I `echo $var`, it shows the result of `123`. Yet when that command is run, it doesn't work - it does not replace `123` with `exampletext`.

Here is the full script:

```
INPUT="$1"

while IFS= read -r line;
do
  if [[ $line == *"length"* ]];
          then

                 var=$(printf "$line" | awk -F':' {'print $2'} | sed 's/,//g')
                 sed -i "s|$var|cookiecrisp|g" "vomit.txt"
  fi
done < $INPUT
```

Comment: is this on mac or linux? I remember on Mac the default sed doesn't do `-i` the way it works on linux. Have you already verified that the sed command run by itself does what you want?

Comment: Linux - Ubuntu 20.04. Yes it does do what I want when run by itself.

Comment: Why not `awk -v var="$var" ' {sub(var,"exampletext",$2)}1'`? The point being here, based on what you have in your question, there doesn't seem to be a need for `sed` and separate subshells. A single call to `awk` should do. If you provide sample data, then we can confirm.

Comment: I suspect that `$var` does not contain "123" but something like " 123", which `echo` will filter out. But it's not possible to say without some example data.

Comment: I discovered that echo is filtering out characters. I ran `wc -m $var` and it gave me this output:  `wc: '225637'$'\r': No such file or directory`

How can I strip out the unnecessary characters?

Comment: `'\r'` -- you have DOS line endings, Run `dos2unix input_file` to convert to Unix line-endings. If you only want to process lines containing `"length"`, then `awk -v var="$var" '/length/ {sub(var,"exampletext",$2)}1'`

Comment: FYI I'm still new to sed/awk. There is a secondary calculation that needs to run against $var, changing it from milliseconds to mm:ss in the final product, before running the sed command. I have yet to add it to the script. That's why I separated it. The final replace value will not be "cookiecrisp" but rather the converted value

Comment: You could also use `IFS=$'\r' read ...` to trim the carriage return in the `read` command (provided you're actually running under bash, not dash). See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings).

Comment: Sure, you can use several commands if needed. The key is to avoid spawning unnecessary subshells within a loop -- that kills shell performance on large files. If you have 1000 or less lines, it doesn't really matter, but for 1,000,000 it matters a lot. `awk` can handle all the processing -- it is the Swiss-Army knife of text processing (basically a small programming language all it's own similar to C in many ways)